# How to set responsive width on inline elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set some buttons on the same line as an input inside of a form. The buttons have to be block elements, I think, because I need to set their width and height in order to keep them circular. The input needs to have a responsive width, preferably about 80% of the container so that the buttons can be set up on either side of the input. The problem I have is that I can't put them on the same line without displaying both the buttons and the input as inline or inline-block, but when I do so, the width of the input won't set at 100%. So, how do I put these things on the same line without compromising the size of the buttons and keeping the input width responsive?

I'm also willing to use flexbox if that would be easier, but knowing how to do it in a semantically correct way in HTML would be really helpful. 
This is probably something that's been asked before, but I've been looking for a while and can't really understand how to fix my specific issue.

CSS:

```
#searchone {
width: 100%;
}

/* ticket number selection */

.ti{
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tickets {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: red;
}

.tickets label {
display: block;
}

.tickets input {
display: inline-block;
}

/* buttons for tickets */

#more,
#less {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #004EA6;
  border-radius:50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="ti">
        <label for="tickets">Tickets</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="tickets">
          <li>
            <label for="adult">Adults</label>
            <input type="text" name="tickets" id="adult" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="1" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="senior">Seniors</label>
            <input type="text" name="tickets" id="senior" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="0" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="children">Children</label>
            <input type="text" name="tickets" id="children" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="0" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="infant">Infants</label>
            <input type="text" name="tickets" id="infant" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="0" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

The buttons are inserted via JS but I don't think you need all of it, so I'll just give you one line of how I did the insertion. The line is duplicated with the id #less and a minus sign instead of the plus.

JS:

```
  $('#adult').after('<a class="ad" id="more" href="#null">+</a>');
```

If you can help or even direct me to a different place that has an answer, thank you!!

Comment: Add width to your inputs as a percentage. It will make the input fields responsive. add this to your CSS and check the result. `input { width: 80%; }`

Comment: @adriano thank you that worked perfectly! i just didn't realize I could do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your button with fixed dimension inside an element with `inline` attribute.